# Facebook Access Tokens / Login

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to write a custom authorize / deauthorize script for my site using Facebook's OAuth token. I can post the token to my database, but when I delete the token and refresh the page, it just posts the token again even though I didn't click the authorize link.

My authorize.php:

```
<div class="authorize_btn" style="float:right; margin-top:-35px; padding-right:10px">
<?php 
    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    { 
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT fb_token FROM users";
    $user   = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query  = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 

    $login = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    $fb_token = $row[0];

    if (empty($fb_token))
    {

        $add_user = "<a href='$login'>Add User</a>";
        echo $add_user; 

        if ($add_user)
        {
            $sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET fb_token='$access_token' where username='$user'");
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<form id='deauth' action='deauth_fb.php' method='post'>";     
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='document.forms[0].submit();'>Deauthorize User</a>";  
        echo "</form>";                                         
    }
?>
</div>
```

My deauth_fb.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include ('inc/facebook.php');
    include ('fbconfig.php');

    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'         => APP_ID, 
        'appSecret'     => APP_SECRET, 
    )); 

    $user_session = $_SESSION['username'];
    $delete_sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET fb_token='' where username='$user_session'");


    header('location:home.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will refresh the Token if it´s still valid, you should use the official way:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are just updating the `fb_token` to `blank` without logging out the user.

To get the logout URL:

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'http://after_logout.lnk' );
$logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

`getLogoutURL()` takes an optional `$params` array containing the key and value pairs:

`next` → (optional) Next URL to which to redirect the user after logging out (should be an absolute URL).

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/)